# Proof $\log_b a\cdot\log_c b\cdot\log_a c=1$,

Tags: logarithms

Please help me proof $\log_b a\cdot\log_c b\cdot\log_a c=1$, where $a,b,c$ positive number different for 1.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Before we prove the given identity proof this idenity

$$\log_b a\log_c b=\log_c a$$

Proof: Implement the formula $\log_a b=\frac{\log_x b}{\log_x a}$

$$\frac{\log a}{\log b}\cdot\frac{\log b}{\log c}=\frac{\log a}{\log c}=\log_c a$$

Now proof the given identity.

$$\log_b a\cdot\log_c b\cdot\log_a c=1$$

$$\log_c a\cdot\log_a c=1$$

$$\frac{1}{\log_a c}\cdot\log_a c=1$$

$$1=1$$

Comment: Your logic is flawed here. For instance, $3 = 0 \Rightarrow 0 \times 3 = 0 \times 0 \Rightarrow 0 = 0$ but that doesn't mean that $3=0$ is true. If anything, a proof would go backwards through what you wrote ;)

Comment: Here's how the last bit should have been written: $\log_b a\cdot\log_c b\cdot\log_a c$ $=\log_c a\cdot\log_a c$ $=\dfrac{1}{\log_a c}\cdot\log_a c = 1$.

Answer (score 9):

Change all to the natural logarithm $\log\,$:

$$\log_ba\cdot\log_cb\cdot\log_ac=\frac{\log a}{\log b}\frac{\log b}{\log c}\frac{\log c}{\log a}$$

and voila.

Comment: ... or to a logarithm of arbitrary base as long as it's the same one everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

${\bf Hint}\quad\begin{array}{cccccc}  &\rm x^{\,I} &\rm C\quad\\
 & \ \nearrow &  \\
\rm A\!\!\!\! &         &  \downarrow \rm x^{\,J} \\  
  &  \nwarrow &  \\
  &\rm x^K           &\rm B\quad\ \ 
\end{array}\rm\  \Rightarrow\ \ IJK\, =\, 1$

Comment: That's an interesting way to put it.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>By definition</strike> $\log_a b = \frac{\log b}{\log a}$.

Comment: This is not true by definition.  It's a provable result.

Comment: Good point. I forget to think of it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\log_b a=x\implies b^x=a,$

$ \log_c b=y\implies c^y=b$ and

$\log_a c=z\implies a^z=c$

Now, $a^z=c\implies (b^x)^z=c\implies ((c^y)^z)^x=c\implies c^{xyz}=c\implies xyz=1$ assuming $c\neq 0,1$

Thus, $xyz=1\implies \log_b a\cdot\log_c b\cdot \log_a c=1$

Comment: See my answer for a more graphic viewpoint.